# Flask SQLAlchemy join query returning [<Service 2>]

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Why is the code

```
        res = Service.query.join(Counter,(Counter.service_id == Service.id)).filter(Service.dept_id == deptId).all()

        print(res)
```

is always returning  []. I want the data in array format.

My Models are as below. Please excuse me if the question is very primitive. I am very new to SQL Alchemy.

```
class Service(FlaskSerializeMixin,db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        ser_name = db.Column(db.String(100),unique=True,nullable=False)
        ser_prefix = db.Column(db.String(1),unique=True,nullable=False)
        cnt_num = db.Column(db.Integer,nullable=False)
        pri_q_flg = db.Column(db.Boolean,nullable=False)
        dept_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('department.id'),nullable=False)
        cre_time =db.Column(db.DateTime)
        chg_time =db.Column(db.DateTime)
        __table_args__ = (
                db.UniqueConstraint('ser_name', 'dept_id', name='unique_service_dept'),
        )
        pqueues = db.relationship('PQueue',backref='service',lazy=True)
        counters = db.relationship('Counter',backref='service',lazy=True)
class Counter(FlaskSerializeMixin,db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        cnt_num = db.Column(db.Integer,nullable=False)
        service_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('service.id'),nullable=False)
        user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
        cre_time =db.Column(db.DateTime)
        chg_time =db.Column(db.DateTime)
        __table_args__ = (
                db.UniqueConstraint('cnt_num', 'service_id', name='unique_cnt_service'),
        )
```

Comment: you mean in list?

Comment: I am not able to parse it.. please help..

Comment: you will get a list of tuple so you can iterate

Comment: Please edit your question. You claim geting `list` - `[]` which may be ambigious in Python world, cause list and array are pretty much synonyms. I assumed that you don't have `array.array` in your mind.

Comment: Also, you can simplify your query with using `res = Service.query.join(Service.counters).filter(Service.dept_id == deptId).all()`